# UIPickerView frame size - margin issue

Tags: iphone, border, uipickerview, margin, frame

I can't seem to find an answer to this one anywhere - hoping someone can help!  Does anyone know how to determine the margins that iOS puts around a picker?

I've written a generic view that displays a UIPickerView with a number of digits and labels in appropriate positions.  The UIPickerView was created in interface builder and fills the whole screen.  I'm currently using the "frame" property of the UIPickerView to determine the width of the picker and calculate the width of individual components and the label positions.

*updated*
As requested - I've tried to include the code.  What I'm building is a generic UIViewController that has a single picker in the associated .xib file - I load it as a modal view whenever I need to input any numeric value, just by giving it the necessary parameters.  The picker is set in Interface Builder to mode "Centered" - I've tried a few others but nothing really seems to make any difference to the layout.

The class takes in the number of digits and the number of decimal places as well as a unit description.  The number of components is then determined by these values and two labels are placed appropriately over the picker components to show the decimal point and the unit label.  The viewDidLoad method is shown below.  It generates a standard component width that's used in the UIPickerView delegate methods.  The maths all seems fine, but the positioning is going wrong and I think it's due to the margin round the edge of the picker.

```
unitLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", unitDescription];
CGSize labelSize = [[unitLabel text] sizeWithFont:[unitLabel font]];
labelWidth = labelSize.width;

decimalPoint.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"."];
CGSize pointSize = [[decimalPoint text] sizeWithFont:[decimalPoint font]];
dpWidth = pointSize.width;
if (decimalPlaces == 0) {
    // Hide the decimal point
    decimalPoint.hidden = YES;
    dpWidth = 0;
}
else {
    decimalPoint.hidden = NO;
}

CGFloat pickerWidth = picker.frame.size.width;
//Now determine the standard component width
componentWidth = (pickerWidth - labelWidth - dpWidth) / (digits + decimalPlaces);   

//Now position the decimal point and label
//The components will be centred on the screen, so the location for the labels will be:
//Decimal point:
//Left position of picker + (componentWidth * digits)
//Unit:
//Left position of picker + (componentWidth * digits) + dpWidth + (componentWidth * decimalPlaces)
//Where:
//Left position of picker = screen width  -  (componentWidth * digits) + dpWidth + (componentWidth * decimalPlaces) + labelWidth
//                          ------------     -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                2                                 2
//
CGFloat leftPos = (picker.frame.size.width / 2) - (((componentWidth * digits) + dpWidth + (componentWidth * decimalPlaces) + labelWidth) / 2);
CGFloat dpPos = leftPos + (componentWidth * digits);
CGFloat labelPos = leftPos + (componentWidth * digits) + dpWidth + (componentWidth * decimalPlaces);

CGRect dpFrame = decimalPoint.frame;
dpFrame.origin.x = dpPos;
dpFrame.origin.y = picker.center.y - (5 * (pointSize.height / 12));
decimalPoint.frame = dpFrame;

CGRect labelFrame = unitLabel.frame;
labelFrame.origin.x = labelPos;
labelFrame.origin.y = picker.center.y - (5 * (labelSize.height / 12));
unitLabel.frame = labelFrame;
```

Comment: Maybe post some of the code you are using. Also, how many components are in your picker?

Comment: Have updated with code as requested - sorry it's a bit lengthy!  The number of components is determined by the number of digits and decimal places in the value to be input, so it varies at run time.